# Trying to build First Mozilla Release (Netscape 5)

Tags: mac-os-classic, netscape

so I've been doing some digging, and I've downloaded the first release of mozilla source code. I'm trying to build it in sheepshaver using codewarrior 4 pro. Ultimately my goal is to try and hack something that will handle HTTPs so that I can at least navigate to web sites that I currently can't see on my classic mac. maybe even

I'm following the build instructions here:
http://marc.info/?l=mozilla-documentation&m=90222373931141

About half way down that page, there are a list of downloads necessary to get Mozilla to build. The problem I'm running into is that after significant digging, I've been able to find alternate links and download all of the dependencies except for 3...

the three I'm missing are:

1. CWASTEEdit: http://www.bact.wisc.edu/CWASTEEdit/CWASTEEdit.sit.hqx
2. Menu Sharing Toolkit: ftp://ftp.scripting.com/userland/menuSharingToolkit4.1.sit.hqx
3. ToolFrontEnd: ftp://dev.apple.com/devworld/Periodicals/develop/develop25/develop_Issue_25_code/ToolFrontEnd.sit.hqx

(obviously the above links are long expired...)

I've managed to find a CWaste 1.0 and later MenuSharing toolkits but they are the wrong versions, so I'm unsure if they will build properly.. if anyone knows where I can locate the versions specified that would be very helpful.

The biggest roadblock however, is the one from apple: 'ToolFrontEnd'. I've got nothing on this one. Does anyone know of an archive of apple's devworld periodicals from 1998?

Edit: I've created a web page detailing my efforts: http://andrew.colchagoff.com/netscape/

Comment: Not to discourage you from trying to do this, but you do know about the [Classzilla project](http://www.floodgap.com/software/classilla/), right? Runs on Mac OS 8.6 and 9. I'm sure they'd love additional contributors!

Comment: I'm aware of Classzilla, but all of my mac retrocomputing is on 68k macs running system 7. so Classzilla doesn't really do me any good. However, downloading the Classzilla source might turn up some of these dependencies.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, even the oldest version of the Mozilla Project (including pre-release versions) requires a PPC processor running 8.6 (or maybe 8.5?), so even if you can get this to compile, I doubt it will help much on your 68k machines. You'd have to make *significant* changes to the source code. iCab used to run on 68k machines, and is still available for download, but not open-sourced, unfortunately. I'm not sure if there are any other options.

Comment: You're probably right, but I'm thinking I want to start with the oldest version possible. there aren't really any other options. my goals aren't strictly utilitarian, I'm an experienced web developer so the source code of Netscape 5 interests me.

Comment: Hi! @ThomasEngelmeier is this your website? http://web.archive.org/web/20020204014027/http://engelmeier.com:80/developer/ToolPostLinker.html can you help me Find ToolFrontEnd?

Comment: well that didn't work...

Comment: That would only work if a user named Thomas Engelmeier had an account on this site *and* had interacted with your question in some way. (Usually by leaving a comment, but it would also work if he'd edited the question or participated in closing it.) Instead, it just notified me, because I was the only person to have commented here. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray yeah I found a question he responded to int he last year and commented on it, we'll see how that goes.

Comment: Is using the old, pre-mozilla 4.7.x netscape not an option?

Comment: @rackandboneman no, everything pre 5 was closed source and was never made available. The release of Netscape 5 source to the public was a pretty unprecedented move at the time. Theres even a documentary about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Q7FTjhvZ7Y

Comment: What does it matter since the goal seems to be running a https capable browser on a classic mac (for which 4.x builds seem to exist)?

Comment: The https in the 4.x browsers is not compatible with ssl certificates issued after a certain date, so all the certificates that it once worked with are long expired.

Comment: Note that the Netscape 5 source is a rewrite that has little to do with the Netscape 4 source (which was not made public).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Obviously the above links are long expired...

The original links may have expired, but the Internet Archive [made a copy of CWASTEEdit](http://web.archive.org/web/19960901000000/http://www.bact.wisc.edu:80/CWASTEEdit/CWASTEEdit.sit.hqx).

The Internet Archive does not archive `ftp` sites, so the file must be found elsewhere. It seems that `ftp://dev.apple.com/` has only disappeared relatively recently - many text files still refer to it. Many mirrors have been made of individual sections, but I haven't yet found any containing the devworld periodicals.

Comment: Good find on the CWASTEEdit, I put at least an hour into archive.org last night looking for that one, but everything ended with an FTP link.

Comment: I did find this on archive.org which mentions some CD's... http://web.archive.org/web/19970615134644/http://www.devworld.apple.com:80/devnews/previousnews.html

Comment: @Denodster Good find - I spent much of the time looking for the http equivalent of devworld and thought it would be developer.apple.com.

Comment: Found something! http://web.archive.org/web/20020204014027/http://engelmeier.com:80/developer/ToolPostLinker.html it turns out the project was forked and renamed ToolPostLinker. but If i can find a download for ToolPostLinker that may work instead.

Comment: @denodster That would effectively be a newer version, and forks are often less concerned about backwards-compatibility so it might not work. However, it's almost definitely better than nothing. Well done!

Comment: @denodster The copy on that site hasn't been archived. :-( [Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20040901094304/http://www.engelmeier.com/downloads/ToolServerPlugins.sit.hqx). Perhaps Google Cache has a copy (_unlikely_).

Comment: I think I've found [Tim Mahoney](https://uk.linkedin.com/in/timothymahoney) but there are lots of Tim Mahoneys so I'm not sure. There's no experience working with Apple on there but I'm not sure how the devworld periodicals were put together. His website consists of a Database Error in `<h1>` font so I can't get information to decide one way or another that way.

Comment: @denodster The correct Tom Engelmeier's email address can be found in [this image](http://web.archive.org/web/20040901170612im_/http://www.engelmeier.com:80/developer/images/tpl.gif). I'm not posting it here because of scrapers.

Comment: I tried emailing last night, but alas both emails on the website are dead. I did however find out that Tom EngelMeier (Author of ToolPostLinker) has a github, so I gave this a shot: https://github.com/tengelmeier/tengelmeier.github.io/pull/1

Comment: @denodster That's... one way of doing it. :-) If he's "watching" too many things, though, the message might not get through as it will be swamped by messages about other software.

Comment: @denodster I noticed that you found it - perhaps you could write up a quick answer including a link (and perhaps a link to your write-up) and a quick summary. (P.S. On your write-up, you should use your affiliate link [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3246/2187) for the badges. Note that the official site name is "Retrocomputing Stack Exchange".)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by affiliate link, but I've uploaded all the dependancies here: http://andrew.colchagoff.com/netscape/

Comment: Also - perhaps you should ask another question about the issue you're getting with the linker. I suspect that it is because C files aren't automatically linked together without including a header file with the prototypes - if you create header files containing the prototype of each "missing" function that might fix the problem.

Comment: @denodster The "affiliate link", officially called the "share link", allows you to gain badges for publicising a question (bronze for 25 unique IPs all the way up to gold for 1000 unique IPs). If your SE account is already clearly linked to (e.g. if it's your own question and you say that it's your own question) I don't see any point _not_ doing that.

Answer (score 5):

I found everything I needed, but the hunting was tough. I've uploaded all of the dependancies as well as the documentation of what I've done so far here:

http://andrew.colchagoff.com/netscape/